# List all used data types of a table or whole database in Oracle DB

Tags: oracle, oracle-10g, sqlite, datatypes

I am preparing a migration from Oracle DB to a SQLite DB.
I would like to know all used datatypes in the Oracle DB so I can check out the equal datatypes in SQLite.

I am sure using Information_Schema seems to be the right way but I don't know how to start.

The used version of the Oracle DB is 10g (10.2).

I am thanking in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example to find the number and type of columns in a schema:

```
select data_type, count(*) from dba_tab_cols
where owner = '...' group by data_type order by data_type

DATA_TYPE              COUNT(*)
-------------------- ----------
ANYDATA                       6
BLOB                         32
CHAR                      12335
CLOB                        259
DATE                      16923
LONG                          2
NUMBER                    39618
NVARCHAR2                     9
RAW                          53
ROWID                       270
TIMESTAMP(3)                 37
TIMESTAMP(6)                109
VARCHAR2                 132291
XMLTYPE                       2
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked! For information on a single table I am using `desc tablename;` (if you have to document every table and its datatypes).